# Haskell random generator wrapped into a function always returns the same value

Tags: haskell, random

Let's assume I execute in GHCi the following code:

```
[unsafePerformIO (randomRIO (0,1)) | _ <- [1..10]].
```

The result may look like `[1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]` and is different every time I execute this.
Now suppose that I have the following function defined:

```
f :: Int
f = unsafePerformIO (randomRIO (0,1))
```

and try to call:

```
[f | _ <- [1..10]].
```

The result is always `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`. And if I just make a single call of `f`, it always returns 0.
Keeping aside that I should not cast IO away, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `unsafePerformIO` don't make function non-pure. Use `sequence [randomRIO (0,1) | _ <- [1..10]]`

Comment: Using `unsafePerformIO` is a big "don't" in Haskell.  Unless you know precisely what you're doing and can ensure that calling `unsafePerformIO` will result in a pure function, don't use it.  For random number generation, you will have to make the generation step live inside `IO` (or inside a `MonadRandom` monad, which I prefer, you'll need to install the `MonadRandom` package).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is using `unsafePerformIO`, especially when you know it's not going to be a function - it will have different outputs for the same inputs.

The reason your evil used of `unsafePerformIO` is not working as you intended is that `f` isn't a function, it's in [Constant applicative form](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constant_applicative_form). It will only be evaluated once, and be the same each time. You can see this by changing its definition to

```
f :: Int
f = unsafePerformIO (putStrLn "generating" >> randomRIO (0,1))
```

"generating" is only printed once.

To make an evil "function", write

```
g :: a -> Int
g a = unsafePerformIO (randomRIO (0,1))

print [g x | x <- [1..10]]
```

This will be evaluated once for each `x`, even if they have the same value. You can see how evil this is by evaluating

```
print [g x | x <- [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
```

The "function" has different outputs for the same input! Leave everything in `Unsafe` alone until you are sure you need it and sure you understand it, and then leave it alone anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer

Answer (score 3):

`unsafePerformIO` doesn't make function non-pure.

Use `sequence` instead:

```
sequence [randomRIO (0,1) | _ <- [1..10]]
>
  [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1]
```

Comment: doesn't make a function PURE, you want to say?

Comment: @AdelNick, pure function always has SAME output on same input.
So, your `f = unsafePerformIO (randomRIO (0,1))` is still pure, even with `unsafePerformIO`

Comment: @AdelNick To clarify this, the thing that makes `unsafePerformIO` so unsafe is that the compiler for most purposes basically *ignores* its impurity, and *treats* expressions using it as if they are pure. This means that it can both choose not to reevaluate it if a pure expression wouldn't need reevaluation, and can choose to inline it in its use sites so that it gets evaluated *more* than you want.